# Passing multiple values on 'IN' where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am tyring to figure out a solution for an issue in where a concurrent program passes in multiple values from a free text field parameter. We are on RDBMS : 11.2.0.3.0 and Oracle Applications : 12.1.3 .The concurrent program calls a custom plsql procedure that produces XML output based on the parameters passed in. I've tried to create the where clause dynamically in efforts to make the sys_refcursor work as shown below. I've also tried regexp_substr to basically create a list of values once the parameter string is passed in and it did not work either. Everything I've tried fails with the error below. Can someone take a look and let me know how can I make this work?

This is the error I am receiving: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275.

Here is an example of the problem.

```
DECLARE
ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
ref_cur   sys_refcursor;
xmldoc  clob;
v_company varchar2(25);
v_major_acct varchar2(150);
v_major_acct_free varchar2(150);
l_length number;
l_offset number := 1;
l_amount number:=16383;
l_rpt_data varchar2(32767);
v_where varchar(32000);

BEGIN

dbms_lob.createtemporary(xmldoc,TRUE);
v_company := '00110';--p_company;
v_major_acct:=('310;765');--p_major_acct; -----> When I pass only one value it works but fails with two values.

IF v_major_acct IS NOT NULL
   THEN
      v_major_acct_free := '';

      SELECT   REPLACE (v_major_acct, ';', ''',''')
        INTO   v_major_acct_free
        FROM   DUAL;

      v_major_acct_free := '(''' || v_major_acct_free || ''')';

      v_where:=v_where||'and major_acct in' || v_major_acct_free;
END IF;

open ref_cur for '
select * from VIEW
WHERE company =nvl(:v_company, company)'||v_where ---v_where contains AND major_acct in ('310','765') but it fails.
using v_company;
ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(ref_cur);
xmldoc := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);
l_length := nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(xmldoc),0);
fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.log, l_length);
    if (nvl(l_length,0) > 0) then
      loop
         exit when l_length <= 0;
         dbms_lob.read (xmldoc, l_amount, l_offset, l_rpt_data);
         fnd_file.put (fnd_file.output, l_rpt_data);
         -- dbms_output.put_line(l_rpt_data);
         l_length := l_length - l_amount;
         l_offset := l_offset + l_amount;
      end loop;
   end if;
   dbms_lob.freetemporary(xmldoc);
   close ref_cur;
   dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(ctx);

exception

   when others then
      dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(ctx);
      fnd_file.put (fnd_file.output, v_major_acct);
      --errbuf := 'Process failed with the following error: '||sqlerrm;
      --retcode := 2;
      --raise_application_error (-20000,'Process Failed'||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
end;
/
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Give us also the error backtrace for the exception ... so as to identify the line on which the exception occurs. You can do so by logging (somewhere) the results of `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace()` in your procedure's exception handler.

Comment: And, for starters, remove the `dbms_lob.createtemporary(xmldoc,TRUE);`. Your call to `dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);` creates a temporary CLOB for you automatically.

Comment: I removed the call to dbms_lob.createtemporary(xmldoc, TRUE); Tried again and I got the same error. This is what the dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace() retruns:ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 818. Also, as I stated before SQLERRM returns: Process failed with the following error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275

Comment: Th trouble is that there are multiple places in your code which may fail with "invalid LOB locator specified". Unless you precisely identify which line is raising the exception, there's nothing I could do to help you. **Remove/Comment out** the exception handler **completely** and post (to your question, not to a comment underneath! use the "edit" link) the complete exception stack of your PLSQL code execution.

Comment: No response? Well, there's no remote performance tuning without proper remote cooperation.